# Create new column in dataframe by applying math operation to column values based on a match

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, startswith

I have the following dataframes:

```
df1
name  phone  duration(m)
Luisa 443442  1
Jack  442334  6
Matt  442212  2
Jenny 453224  1

df2
prefix charge rate
443     0.8   0.3
446     0.8   0.4
442     0.6   0.1
476     0.8   0.3
```

my desired output is to match each phone number with its prefix (there are more prefixes than phone numbers) and calculate how much to charge per called by multiplying the duration of call for each phone number by the corresponding prefix charge plus the corresponding rate.

output ex.

```
df1
    name  phone  duration(m) bill
    Luisa 443442  1          (example: 1x0.3+0.8)
    Jack  442334  6          (example: 6x0.1+0.6)
    Matt  442212  2
    Jenny 453224  1
```

my idea was to convert df2 to a dictionary like so dict={'443':[0.3,0.8],'442':[0.1,0.6]...} so i could match each number with the dict key and then do the opertion with the corresponding value of that matching key. However is not working and would also like to know if there is a better alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name':["Louisa","Jack","Matt","Jenny"],'phone':[443442,442334,442212,453224],'duration':[1,6,2,1]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'prefix':[443,446,442,476],'charge':[0.8,0.8,0.6,0.8],'rate':[0.3,0.4,0.1,0.3]})

df3=pd.concat((df1,df2),axis=1)

df4=pd.DataFrame({"phone_pref":df3["phone"].astype(str).str[:3]})
df4=df4["phone_pref"].drop_duplicates()

df3["bill"]=None
for j in range(len(df4)):
    for i in range(len(df3["prefix"])):
        if df3.loc[i,"prefix"]==int(df4.iloc[j]):
            df3.loc[i,"bill"]=df3.loc[i,"duration"]*df3.loc[i,"charge"]+df3.loc[i,"rate"]
print(df3)

   duration    name   phone  charge  prefix  rate  bill
0         1  Louisa  443442     0.8     443   0.3   1.1
1         6    Jack  442334     0.8     446   0.4  None
2         2    Matt  442212     0.6     442   0.1   1.3
3         1   Jenny  453224     0.8     476   0.3  None
```

The None values in the bill column are because in your excample no phone number has the prefixes 446 or 476 and thus they are not in the df4...
Also the bill is calculated with the formula of yours given in the question

Comment: The dataframes used for the questions are examples i have hundred of log calls records and prefixes. I have run the code but it seems to be matching the prefixes with the phone numbers in a way that it will match if the prefix is contained in a phoen number. For example i have prefix 441 matched with a phone number 4474441

Comment: Normally thats not possible because only the df3[prefix] column is matched with the df4 which also only contains the first 4 chars

Comment: thank you is there a way to achive this then? just mathcin the prefixes which can vary in leght to the phone numbers?

Comment: Youre welcome. You can try it with regular expressions if you know the exact shape of the prefixes. Also for that you must know the "rules" after which the prefixes are distributed

Comment: So I mean you must know the rules after which the prefixes are allocated. For example if the prefixes also match perfectly to the beginning of the numbers then regexpressions will be fine

Comment: You can read an excellent introduction to regular expressions at: http://www.python-course.eu/re.php

Answer (score 2):

To merge with prefix of arbitrary length you can do

```
>> df1['phone'] = df1.phone.astype(str)
>> df2['prefix'] = df2.prefix.astype(str)
>> df1['prefix_len'] = df1.phone.apply(
       lambda h: max([len(p) for p in df2.prefix if h.startswith(p)] or [0]))
>> df1['prefix'] = df1.apply(lambda s: s.phone[:s.prefix_len], axis=1)
>> df1 = df1.merge(df2, on='prefix')
>> df1['bill'] = df1['duration(m)'] * df1['rate'] + df1['charge']
>> df1
   duration(m)   name    phone  prefix_len  prefix  charge  rate    bill
0            1  Luisa   443442           3     443     0.8   0.3     1.1
1            6   Jack   442334           3     442     0.6   0.1     1.2
2            2   Matt   442212           3     442     0.6   0.1     0.8
```

Note that

- in case of multiple prefixes I choose the one with maximum length;
- in case when there are no prefixes for particular phone I fill its length with default zero value, (then `s.phone[:s.prefix_len]` will produce an empty prefix and `pd.merge` will eliminate those phones from the result).

Comment: Thank you it is a simple way and it works however this was only an example and unfortunately i also have prefixes which are longer not always just 3 chars long so i can't slice the numbers always in the first 3 letters.

Comment: @Ana Check updated answer for the case when phones may be with prefixes of different length.

Comment: Is there a module requirement for this to work? I am getting the follwing error: TypeError: max() got an unexpected keyword argument

Comment: @Ana Yes, sorry, I did not mension the python version, actually `default` argument is for python3.4+. I updated the answer to work with python2.

Comment: Thank you so much! Thank you for the help and clear code :)